# Count number of steps a timeseries and find which step had max duration using R

Tags: r

I have a timeseries dataset like so:

```
Time_TS    Step
17:54:41    0
17:54:43    0
17:54:45    0
17:54:46    1
17:54:47    1
17:54:48    1
17:54:49    1
17:54:50    0
17:54:51    0
17:54:54    0
17:54:55    0
17:54:56    1
17:54:57    1
17:54:59    1
17:55:01    1
17:55:03    0
17:55:08    0
17:55:10    0
17:55:14    1
17:55:15    1
17:55:20    0
17:55:21    0
17:55:23    0
17:55:24    0
17:55:26    0
17:55:27    0
17:55:30    0
17:55:31    0
17:55:35    1
17:55:37    1
17:55:41    1
17:55:43    1
17:55:45    1
17:55:48    0
17:55:53    0
17:55:56    0
17:55:59    0
17:56:02    0
```

I would like to calculate the duration within each group where the Step=1 and then find the max duration within those grouped duration.

If I were to use typical first principles I would iteratively identify when the `step` changed from `0` to `1` and `1` to `0`, store the timestamps and then subtract them.
But this doesn't seem elegant at all, and I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it in R.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that there's a more elegant or vectorized way to do this unless you know something about when the step changes. What is this data from?

Comment: Could add groups with `dplyr::mutate(dataset, group = cumsum(Step))`, then get all data with `Step=1` with `dplyr::filter(dataset, Step == 1)`, then group the data and summaries the range: `dplyr::group_by(dataset, group)` `dplyr::summarise(dataset, duration = diff(range(Time_TS))`, finally extracting the max with `dplyr::slice_max(dataset, duration)`

Comment: Perhaps you may need `rle/rleid` i.e. `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, c('grp', 'Time_TS') := .(rleid(Step), hms::as_hms(Time_TS))];df1[Step == 1, .(minT = min(Time_TS), maxT = max(Time_TS)), grp][, diffT := maxT - minT][]`

Comment: @Baraliuh When I try the `mutate(dataset, group = cumsum(Step))` I only get `NA` for `group`. 
The `Step` column is of `int` datatype

Comment: @luke This is just a simple DAQ of a valve when it opens and closes. the `1` represents when the valve is open.

Comment: @thentangler Then you have to filter out missing values first or add the `na.rm = T` flag in `cumsum`

Comment: Is a duration the time "while Step known to be 1" or "until Step changes to 0"?

Comment: @JonSpring It is until step changes to `0`. So in the above example I gave there are 4 groups where `step=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `dplyr`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
time <- c(
"17:54:41", 
"17:54:43",
"17:54:45",   
"17:54:46",  
"17:54:47",    
"17:54:48",    
"17:54:49",    
"17:54:50",    
"17:54:51",    
"17:54:54",    
"17:54:55")
stage <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(time, stage)

newstage <- c(-1, diff(stage))!=0
df$stageid <- cumsum(newstage)

df$hms <-  strptime(df$time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
       time stage stageid                 hms
1  17:54:41     1       1 2022-07-13 17:54:41
2  17:54:43     1       1 2022-07-13 17:54:43
3  17:54:45     1       1 2022-07-13 17:54:45
4  17:54:46     0       2 2022-07-13 17:54:46
5  17:54:47     0       2 2022-07-13 17:54:47
6  17:54:48     0       2 2022-07-13 17:54:48
7  17:54:49     1       3 2022-07-13 17:54:49
8  17:54:50     1       3 2022-07-13 17:54:50
9  17:54:51     0       4 2022-07-13 17:54:51
10 17:54:54     0       4 2022-07-13 17:54:54
11 17:54:55     0       4 2022-07-13 17:54:55
```

I assigned an unique stage id to all data, then calculate the duration for each stage ID.

```
mysummary <- df %>% filter(stage==1) %>% 
  group_by(stageid) %>% 
  summarise(duration=difftime(max(df$hms),min(hms), units="secs"))
maxstage <- mysummary[which.max(mysummary$duration),]
# to go back to the original data just use the stage id
result <- df %>% filter(stageid == maxstage$stageid)

      time stage stageid                 hms
1 17:54:41     1       1 2022-07-13 17:54:41
2 17:54:43     1       1 2022-07-13 17:54:43
3 17:54:45     1       1 2022-07-13 17:54:45
```

Comment: This is kind of what i was looking for. In your dataframe, you have 2 groups where `stage` = `1`.  stageid `1` and stageid `3`. But how come end up with 3 `stage=1` in your result?

Comment: these are the 3 original lines of the data for which the stage id is 1. I had to create a new reproducible example since you didnt provide one

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(Step != lag(Step, default = Inf)) %>%
  mutate(duration = lead(Time_TS) - Time_TS) %>%
  filter(Step == 1) %>%
  filter(duration == max(duration))
```

This identifies the start of the occasion where Step == 1 and the longest duration happens before Step changes to 0.

```
   Time_TS Step duration
1 17:55:35    1  13 secs
```

---

```
df <- data.frame(
     Time_TS = c("17:54:41","17:54:43","17:54:45",
                 "17:54:46","17:54:47","17:54:48","17:54:49","17:54:50","17:54:51",
                 "17:54:54","17:54:55","17:54:56","17:54:57","17:54:59",
                 "17:55:01","17:55:03","17:55:08","17:55:10","17:55:14",
                 "17:55:15","17:55:20","17:55:21","17:55:23","17:55:24",
                 "17:55:26","17:55:27","17:55:30","17:55:31","17:55:35","17:55:37",
                 "17:55:41","17:55:43","17:55:45","17:55:48","17:55:53",
                 "17:55:56","17:55:59","17:56:02"),
        Step = c(0L,0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,
                 1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,0L,0L,1L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,
                 0L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L)
) %>%
  mutate(Time_TS = hms::as_hms(Time_TS))
```